# automatically declare object class variable when creating new sheet in EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

How do I declare a - private - class variable, when a new sheet is created using the tab. It has to be done automatically. I presume it is a good idea to declare it by using the
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object) -event from the Wookbook object

```
    Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
        Dim sh.privateVariableOfSheet As Integer
        Declare New sh.privateVariableOfSheet2 As Integer
    End Sub
```

Both above 'declarations' fails of course!

And for the completeness, how to refer to this variable from an ordinary module.

Comment: what type of Variable/Class you want to get ? What type of events ?

Comment: @Shai Rado: It is all in the code example: when a new sheeet is initiated / created then the Workbook-NewSheet routine is triggered (the event). And I want to declare a variable (type Range to refer to the second last selection of the sheet - for later use) in this new sheet WITHOUT using the VBAeditor.

Comment: You can't do that without automating the VBE to add code to the worksheet. It would be easier to copy an existing sheet that already has the variable if you can. I'm not really clear why you need to do this.

Comment: @Rony.  I need to keep track of the last selected cell - not the present one - for EACH of the many sheets I have at a certain time and I thought that a variable à la ' oldSelectedCell' would be the way of doing it.

Comment: @Ralph. That looks very nice. I'll try it out

Comment: IMO it would be easier to use a collection in `ThisWorkbook` and a `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` event.

Comment: Why, when a sheet is an object (which is probably been created with a new-statement... when its created) could a simple variable not be created with VBA EASYLY?

Comment: Because you're trying to add a property to an object at runtime, which is not normal. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method is to use the [`CustomProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197822.aspx) collection of the `Worksheet`. For example:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Sh.CustomProperties.Add Name:=Sh.Name, Value:=99

End Sub
```

You can then use it later in a sub-routine:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim var As Variant

    var = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet13").CustomProperties(1)

    MsgBox var

End Sub
```

Comment: You're quite busy. I go for this one. BUT great to see your other treatease using classes.

Answer (score 1):

Let take some class - `clsFoo` - which has a single property of type `Range` with a getter and setter:

```
Private m_rngSomewhere As Range

Public Property Get SomeRange() As Range
    Set SomeRange = m_rngSomewhere
End Property

Public Property Set SomeRange(rng As Range)
    Set m_rngSomewhere = rng
End Property
```

Now, in the `Workbook` code module you have:

- a `Public` variable which we will set as a `Dictionary`
- a `Sub` to instantiate the `Dictionary` - could be called from `Workbook_Open` or something
- an event handler for `Workbook_NewSheet`

The event handler creates a new instance of `clsFoo` and sets its property as a `Range` from the new `Worksheet`, and then adds that to the dictionary (and checks if it was already there for some new reason).

Code in Workbook module:

```
Option Explicit

Public SheetFooDic As Object

Public Sub InitialiseSheetFooDic()
    Set SheetFooDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cls As clsFoo
    If Not SheetFooDic.Exists(Sh) Then
        Set rng = Sh.Range("A1")
        Set cls = New clsFoo
        Set cls.SomeRange = rng
        SheetFooDic.Add Sh, cls
    End If
End Sub
```

This leaves you needing to simply use some `Worksheet` object as a key into the `Dictionary` in order to retrieve the `Range` you stored when the `Worksheet` was created. You can refer to the public `Dictionary` like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.SheetFooDic(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")).SomeRange.Address
```

And get:

```
$A$1
```

Comment: Nice solution, maybe the one I'll use. Though I thought it could be done with less 'work' (as I wrote a kind of Dim/Declare ...)

Comment: Hope it helps. Regarding the 'amount of work' - personally to me, it seems simpler than injecting some code into a worksheet. You would need to keep that 'hard-coded' code somewhere and maintain it over time.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the address of the last selected cell as a string. So, asking for an object variable might be misleading. Either way, the easiest way is to declare a public variable (for example `PrevCell As String`, or As Range if you prefer or need the value) in each of your worksheets' code and set that variable in each sheet's Selection_Change event procedure.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    PrevCell = Target.Cells(1)     ' or .Address
End Sub
```

Since you may find it useful to avoid recording selections of multiple cells my above procedure just records the address of the first cell which avoid errors that often crop up when a copy/paste action was performed on a sheet.

Now, when you insert a new sheet, don't use the Add method. Instead copy an existing sheet and clean it up the way you want. In this way the new sheet will already have the variable and the code that sets it.

I can't imagine your having need of the previous cell in any circumstance other than when the sheet is activated, but if my imagination is insufficient in this case, you might declare a global array with an element for each sheet, using the sheets' `CodeName` property for identification. This array would be set by the Selection_Change event procedure as demonstrated above, but when a sheet which isn't known to the array tries to register its latest selection it must be a new sheet and the array is extended to include it. The code to do so is inherited from other sheets by the same method described above.